# How to connect to remote sql server from a windows virtualbox hosted locally on machine?

Tags: sql-server, virtualbox, windows-server-2012

I have created a windows virtual box hosted on my machine. There are services hosted on the windows virtual machine which are connecting to a sql server database which is hosted at some remote location.

These services are not able to connect to the remote sql server. The virtual machine is able to ping to remote server successfully but is not establishing connection to sql server.

Please suggest what am i missing, TCP/IP is already enabled. The remote sql server is set to be accessed by any machine so, i don't see anything missing from the sql server end it is my windows virtual machine which is missing some setting. Hence provide suggestions please.

Comment: Is SQL Browser Service running on the machine where SQL Server is running ?

Comment: @GuidoG yes sql browser service is running where SQL server is running

Comment: maybe your connectionstring  is not correct. I suggest creating a textfile with extension `.UDL` Then double click it and use this form to enter and test your connection. If you succeed than open the file with notepad to find the correct settings for your connection